# ng-repeat with radio box did not trigger on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Not sure what is going on. I want to trigger a function when on change and pass the obj to it. As I know since it's bind to selected obj so I can just use ng-model. But in this case nothing changed when I switch the radio button around.

```
 <label ng-repeat="obj in dayGroups">
        <input ng-model="selectedDayGroup" type="radio" name="dayGroups"> {{obj.name}}
      </label>

<!-- nothing happens -->
{{selectedDayGroup}}

//init
$scope.selectedDayGroup = null;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a5rL8cda/

Comment: Matt's answer is correct. I'd like to add that you don't need to initialize  variables that you are going to ng-model. Saves lines of code when you are data binding a bunch of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `value` or `ng-value`. Also since you're in an ng-repeat you'll have to use `$parent` to get to the scope you want:

```
<body ng-controller="Channels">
  <label ng-repeat="obj in dayGroups">
    <input ng-model="$parent.selectedDayGroup" type="radio" name="dayGroups" ng-value="obj"> {{obj.name}}
  </label>

  {{selectedDayGroup}}
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ud0gcpro/

Answer (score 0):

NG-Repeat creates an isolated scope, therefore you can't change the outer controller scope variables like that.

You can either use $parent to explicitly select the outer scope variable, or you can use controller-as syntax explicitly select the outer scope. I prefer the latter.

And as others say, use ng-value or value (for strings only) for your input.